# Duplicating rows based on a multiplier

Tags: r, tidyr

Using R and having some trouble manipulating my data. I've identified bee collected pollen to types and their relative volumes ("adjusted_volume" below) (how much pollen on a slide). I'm now trying to calculate average pollen usage by bees at each of my 14 sites. My data looks like this:

> head(pollen)
>
> ```
>           site    treatment hive_code     pollen_type adjusted_volume
>              A conventional         4       alnus_spp           248.5
>              B conventional         4       alnus_spp            71.0
>              B conventional         7       alnus_spp            35.5
> ```

My plan was to dcast and gather to get the amount of each pollen type per site...

> data1 <- dcast(pollen, site + treatment ~ pollen_type, length)
>
> data2 <- gather(data1, pollen_type, count, alnus_spp:vaccinium_corymbosum, factor_key=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)

But that doesn't account for the differences in volume for each entry. I might be thinking about this the wrong way, but is there a way to multiply each row by the adjusted_volume number in the dcast function? So the first row would count as 248.5 alnus_spp at site A instead of just 1 record?

Thanks for your help in advance! And sorry if I'm going about this in a ridiculous way!

Edit:

This worked! Thanks all!

> x <- ddply(pollen, .(site,  pollen_type, treatment, hive_code), summarise, tot_pollen =  sum(adjusted_volume))

```
> head(x)
>    site                     pollen_type    treatment    hive_code tot_pollen
>       A                          alnus_spp conventional         1      497.0
>       A                          alnus_spp conventional         5      142.0
>       A                    graminaceae_spp conventional         1       29.0
```

Comment: Could you please add an example of what correct output would look like, preferably based on sample data you've provided? Is the task is to get the mean of `adjusted_volume` for each combination of site, treatment, and pollen_type that exists in the data?

Comment: You may need to add a sequence column i.e. `dcast(setDT(pollen), site + treatment + rowid(site, treatment) ~ pollen_type, value.var = "adjusted_volume")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this might get at what you are looking for:

ddply(pollen, .(site,  treatment, pollen_type), summarise, tot_pollen =  sum(adjusted_volume))

This should summarize the volumes of pollen by site, treatment, and pollen_type.

Good luck!